# node-sass-middleware is not installing and showing an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, node-sass

```
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Major Project 1\codeial\node_modules\node-sass-middleware\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\Major Project 1\codeial\node_modules\node-sass-middleware\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
```

Comment: Your node-tar version is out dated. Please get the latest node tar version 6.1.11. Your current version is 2.2.2. And that's what causing this error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.